# Rails Concatenated Query Result "where"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have concatenated two query results and would like to limit the results based on a particular criteria.

```
def all_notifications
  return (user_project_notifications+followed_comments).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
end
```

I'd like to limit all_notifications by those that come after a certain time, so something like:

```
def new_notifications(notifications_last_viewed)
  return all_notifications.where('created_at >?, notifications_last_viewed)
end
```

However, I'm getting the error **undefined method `where' for Array:...**

How can I perform a "where" query on a concatenated result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, because after you apply one of typical `Array` (or `Enumerable`) methods (for example "+") on `ActiveRecord::Relation`, it returns `Array` instance, which doesn't have `ActiveRecord` methods.

I think you should fetch your `user_project_notifications` and `followed_comments` in one query with "OR" - you will then have `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance, on which you can call scope methods, like `order` or `where`.

Comment: ok, I see. now to figure out how to get followed_comments from an activerecord query...

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing a db sort, replace:

```
(user_project_notifications+followed_comments).sort_by(&:created_at).reverse
```

with:

```
(user_project_notifications + followed_comments).order('created_at DESC')
```

You'll keep an relation instead of getting an array.

I guess the issue stems from the `+` where you sum arrays whereas you should join queries.

A good way to do it is to use [this gem](https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of)

Comment: I had this originally but I get the error "undefined method 'order' for Array".  That's why I ended up using sorted and reverse.

Comment: it's important to avoid querying the db so that you can chain queries. I guess the issue stems from the `+` where you sum arrays whereas you should join queries. a good way to do it is to use this gem: https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of

Comment: @apneadiving calling `+` on `ActiveRecord::Relation` returns `Array` instance.

Comment: @apneadiving right. :) I think you should edit your answer to avoid such misundesrtandings.